# Prepare For Segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have learned how to pass data from **ViewController1** to **ViewController2**. Using the prepareForSegue method. What I do not understand is how to pass data back from **ViewController2** to **ViewController1**. Do I just create another segue going back to **ViewController1**, along with a whole new prepareForSegue method in **ViewController2**? Or is there a way to reduce the code and use the original prepare for segue in **ViewController1**?

Comment: The usual ways are protocol/delegate or – more contemporary – a callback closure to be called in `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: No, don't use another segue, you don't want to make new instance of vc1. You may use _delegate pattern_, or you may use your data source (depends on data model). I recommend to read some docs/templates about delegate pattern in iOS **upd** and closures for sure, how did I forgot